# Automatically generating raster maps (from OSM) for areas bounded by polygons?

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap

In order to create walking lists for a volunteer campaign I have used qgis to draw polygons over groups of addresses.  These are irregular areas, so I've used postgis's `ST_ENVELOPE` function to generate rectangular bounding boxes for these areas.

I am looking for way to automatically generate fixed-size raster maps for each of these rectangular bounding boxes.  That is, as output I want to have files named something like `map-for-bb-1.png`, `map-for-bb-2.png`, etc.

Doing this manually seems to be quite time consuming (zoom to an appropriate level of detail on the OSM map, save as a raster image, export the rectangular bounding box as a shapefile, use that as a clipping mask for the raster layer, etc...)

How would I go about automating this?  It seems like some of the steps could be performed on the command line (e.g., using pgsql2shp to export each bounding box to an individual shapefile), but I'm not sure the best way to accomplish some of the remaining steps (e.g., downloading OSM raster data for the corresponding rectangle).

Comment: How are you getting the raster maps at present? I would perhaps look for an OSM WMS, and use a bounding box  to request the image and save it to disk.